# Why does every object in Java implicitly extend java.lang.Object class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, design-patterns

I have been programming in Java for quite some time, but when I tried to explain what an `java.lang.Object` class is to a friend, I could not come up with more than a simple one-liner:

> All objects in Java extend `java.lang.Object` implicitly

I was not quite sure why it should do so.

So, I looked upon the source code on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java), hoping that I can find some clues. Now I know what a `java.lang.Object` is and what it does, I want to know if there was any specific reason as to why it was designed this way.

My question still prevails: why should every object extend `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: So that you can confidently call Object methods on any object.

Comment: I was confused at first, but are you essentially asking *why* Java has a single-rooted class hierarchy? (As opposed to allowing things descend from some other root class)

Comment: Every object is an `Object` as it is useful to have functionality which is common to all objects.

Comment: I voted to close because your *"Why should every object extend it?"* isn't clear. There are methods on object, methods that are available for every object. So the answer is so obvious that there must be something worrying you and that something isn't clear.

Comment: So, its simply a design decision, is there any more than that to it?

Comment: Why? to ensure classes can call Object's methods.

Comment: If your question is "Why is it implicit ?" then the answer is that Java was already winning the race for the most verbose language, so adding "extends Object" to all source files wasn't needed.

Comment: @dystroy My question was why dont was not regarding the syntax... or why not add another 2 extra words in all the source files.

Answer (score 43):

I would say that the reason is to have a common API for all objects in java to supports basic functionality like

- **synchronization** - `wait`, `notify`,  `notifyAll`
- **garbage collection** - `finalize`
- **collection support** - `hashCode`, `equals`
- **object cloning** - `clone`

And every object

- has a class it belongs to - `getClass`
- can represent itself as a string, because we are 
  humans and can read strings - `toString`

Answer (score 9):

This is how the language is designed. Every object will inherit from the base class `Object`. This means that it's guaranteed for every object there will be  certain methods, like `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I think the most important use of `Object` is not to provide common methods like `toString()` but to provide a common **type** that would hold all reference types.

C++ don't have an `Object` equivalent and people are still happy. But since Java don't have pointers and C++-like templates, `Object` is required to make implementations of `Collection`s, etc. possible.

See also on discussions on reference and primitive types.

Answer (score 5):

I would say `Design`. Common/Mandatory methods which every `Object` should support written there and extending that class as a language specification.

You find the reasons here in [Official Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html).

If we are saying this is an `Object` ,They must have the common methods, Which defined/decided by `API`.

**Imagine the below methods  for every class on your Own.**

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
      Creates and returns a copy of this object.


public boolean equals(Object obj)
      Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.


protected void finalize() throws Throwable
      Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage
      collection determines that there are no more references to the object


public final Class getClass()
      Returns the runtime class of an object.


public int hashCode()
      Returns a hash code value for the object.


public String toString()
      Returns a string representation of the object.
```

The notify, notifyAll, and wait methods of Object all play a part in synchronizing the activities of independently running threads in a program:

```
public final void notify()
public final void notifyAll()
public final void wait()
public final void wait(long timeout)
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

So to reduce the pain, created a common and standard `API`.

Comment: Arguably, `clone` should have belonged to a "magical" `CloneableObject` base class, and `finalize` should have been replaced with a "register for cleanup notification" method.  Having universal functions to find out an object's class, though, and define an equivalence relation is helpful [the latter would be even more helpful if objects had separate pairs of equals/hashCode methods which consistently define the two universal equivalence relations, rather than using one pair of methods but being inconsistent about which relation it implements].

Answer (score 5):

Every Class extends Object class implicitly so that they provide basic features which according to Java recommendation every class should have. Such as clone(), equals(), hashCode(), toString(), etc.

By implicitly, it means that if you are not extending any class then only compiler will implicitly extends Object class.But if class already extends other class then compiler will not extend Object class. For eg.
Class A{
}

Class B extends A{
}

Here compiler will implicitly add extends Object class in class A declaration.

Class A **extends Object**{
}

Class B extends A{
}

As class A extends Object class so it will provide basic functionality of Object class such as equals(), toString(),etc. And since Class B extends class A which implicitly extends Class Object, so class B also provides all those features.

Thus by following this approach every class objects(variables) complies to features which every Java Object should have, without going for Multiple Inheritance (a class extending more than one class) which Java doesn't allows. This approach follows Multi-Level Inheritance.

Comment: I also believe that the extension of Object class by default enforces that the 'Multiple Inheritance' is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is done so as most of the basic functions like toString() etc would be automatically inherited and to your next question this is **NOT** multiple inheritence it is **multilevel** inheritence...
In **multiple inheritence** single class is derived from 2 or more base class whereas in multilevel as you have said it has a base class which is itself derived from Object class

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Head first Java 2nd edition:

> Without a common superclass for everything in Java, there’d be no way
>   for the developers of Java to create classes with methods that could
>   take your custom types... types they never knew about when they wrote
>   the ArrayList class.

Which essentially explains the need of a generic predefined class type in Java, which can be used to implement the different features provided by the language.

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html):

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the
>   instance methods of Object. You need not use any of these methods,
>   but, if you choose to do so, you may need to override them with code
>   that is specific to your class.

The `Object` class simply defines the basic state that **all** objects must have - Like comparing it to other objects.

It's the *parent* class of everything. It simply provides kind of *template* to all the derived objects.

Comment: Yes, but OP asks *why*

Answer (score 2):

It's a java design decision. It puts to use the concept of inheritance and re-usabilty. This ensures that all classes have some basic methods like `wait()`, `toString()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Object class is the most super class of java programming, It has predefined methods according to types, you can use those methods. & you don't need to extends object class anymore & anywhere it's implicitly there

Comment: Doesn't say *why.* Not that it's a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Every class in Java is a descendent (direct or indirect) of the Object class. The Object class defines the basic state and behavior that all objects must have, such as the ability to compare oneself to another object, to convert to a string, to wait on a condition variable, to notify other objects that a condition variable has changed, and to return the object's class.