# benefits of inherting from object class

Tags: java

Every class seems to inherit from `Object` class. But I was wondering what are the benefits or why is it required. ?

If you want to use methods inherited from `Object` class - you can't do it unless you override them. For instance - `equals` method or `toString` method. all these must be overridden.

And if you have provide the implementation anyway then I don't see the point of inheriting the `object` class ?

simply put - what are the benefits of inhering from the `object` class ?

Comment: its too old question, google it

Comment: You don't have to provide an implementation yourself. Object class has one for you. It is only when you don't want to use the default behavior that you go for overriding them.

Comment: Thats the whole idea of object oriented programming. You need to brush up your OOP knowledge and I am sure you will yourself find answer to this question.

Comment: Look at all  available methods in Object class.

Comment: @  Subhrajyoti Majumder - I did - And I did not get an answer. Do you mind answering it.

Comment: you study Threads then you will know why notify and notifyAll, you study comparator and comparable and sorting and searching collections then you know equals and hashcode

Comment: infact I also tried looking at the code - but cannot see it - they are native

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114997/why-does-every-object-in-java-implicitly-extend-java-lang-object-class/19115222#19115222

Comment: Can you provide implementation of Object's native methods?

Comment: The keyword here is _polymorphism_!

Comment: @R.J - I bet you to show me the duplicate on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

> But I was wondering what are the benefits or why is it required. ?

Inheritance theory applies here.

Common methods that every **actual Object** must support are separated and defined in `Object` class.

> you can't do it unless you override them.

No,  there is default implementation for methods in Object ,So that you will not end up in writing basic functionality of your each `class`.

Comment: you cannot use clone() on the instance of your class. can you ? I

Comment: +1.. Also, during or after GC, everything is considered as an Object (finalize is called for unreachable objects)

Comment: far more important: the JVM can't instantiate anything that doesn't derive from Object, so whatever class you could theoretically create using a hacked compiler that doesn't derive from Object would never be loaded, making that class utterly useless.

Comment: @jwenting If an hacker derived whole class and trying to inject in to JVM, why won't he just extends with it Object  ;)  He might be a dumb hacker.

Comment: @user3889926 As a developer,you won't always override the methods from Object class .It depends on the requirement. To provide a simple example,equals method works well on primitive types and not on the custom objects created.So it is the design decision from the java gurus.
Please refer the page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html for more info.

Comment: @user3889926 clone() will always yield an Exception unless you've implemented the Cloneable interface and the clone() method (latter might not be technically required, but you'll get a rather useless clone if you don't.