# Classes Extending Object

Tags: java

If every class extends Object, then how does the explicit "extends" keyword to another class work? Does this mean that the current class doesn't extend Object anymore or does it mean it extends two classes?

Comment: posible dupliacte of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114997/why-does-every-object-in-java-implicitly-extend-java-lang-object-class

Comment: Read the duplicates, but in short: if you create a class by extending another, the "another" class still originates from Object (either directly or through further extension), so will your actual class, through `inheritance`.

Comment: You should just learn about inheritance principles.

Comment: I am learning inheritance and thats the reason I'm asking this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every classes is a Sub class to Object Class. if you are extending your own class with another class. That super class is also a sub class of Object class.

**Suppose:**

```
Class A // extends Object
{
}
Class B extends A
{
}
```

here i am extending Class `B` with `A`. Even though Class B has all the features of **Object class** through Class `A`

Comment: So does this mean that Class B doesn't extend Object anymore?

Comment: Class B still getting all the features of Object class through Class A. Because class A is a subclass to Object class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A // extends Object
{
}
Class B extends A {

}
```

---

`Class B` extends `Class A` **directly** and `Class Object` **transitively**

Answer (score 1):

Many things in programming work in accordance to real life situations. Think about Animals.

- Animals. Animals can eat.
- Mammals are Animals. Mammals produce milk.
- Felidaes are Mammals. Felidaes are Carnivores.
- Lions are Felidaes. Lions has attributes of all the above.

Implementing the above with Java classes.

```
class Animal{
    //can eat
} 

class Mammal extends Animal{
    //can eat
    //produce milk
}

class Felidae extends Mammal{
    //can eat
    //produce milk
    //carnivore
}

class Lion extends Felidae{
    //can eat
    //produce milk
    //carnivore
    //roars
}

class PussyCat extends Felidae{
    //can eat
    //produce milk
    //carnivore
    //meows
}
```

Since mammals are animals, if lion is a mammal, that automatically categorizes lions as animals too, thus receiving every attribute of an animal.

Lions are subset of `Animal`, `Mammal` and `Felidae`, it posses all attributes of its `super class`. `PussyCat` shares the same "ancestors" (super class) with `lions`, thus it **inherits** the same attributes and behaviours, except that it meows instead of roars.

---

> Does this mean that the current class doesn't extend Object anymore or does it mean it extends two classes?

In Java everything extends from Object. Even if you don't do it, it implicitly extends Object for you.

Hence you can safely assume every classes you creates are subclasses of Object and they all includes methods from Object such as `toString()` and `clone()`.

You can't extend more than one class in Java, but it is still a subclass of `Object`.