# This method (setSize, setDefaultCloseOperation... is undefined for the type HelloFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to make a swing version of the Hello World!!! program in a GUI. But I keep on getting an error like I mentioned in the title. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new HelloFrame();
    }

    public HelloFrame()
    {
        this.setSize(200, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(
            JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Hello World!");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Errors are in:

```
    this.setSize(200, 100);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(
        JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Hello World!");
    this.setVisible(true);
```

I would really appreciate some answers. Thanks!

EDIT 1: Oh yeah! I forgot to mention I'm using java.

Comment: Please archive this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `HelloFrame` [implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19114997/230513) extends `Object`. As a result, `this` refers to an `Object`, which has no `JFrame` methods. Instead, let `HelloFrame` *contain* a `JFrame`, as shown below. Also,

- I've added a `JLabel` to give the frame something to display after `pack()` is invoked.
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016671/230513 */
public class HelloFrame {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("HelloFrame");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Hello World!");
        f.add(new JLabel("Hello World! Hello World!"), JLabel.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new HelloFrame()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it out now.

Comment: It works! I will figure out how to add some sort of button to trigger the Hello World! Thing.

Comment: Ok trashgod.   I will try it out.

Comment: See also [*How to Use Buttons*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will try it out.

Comment: Is it okay if you tell me how you figured this out or any sources you have used? Thanks.

Comment: @Cakedy: In addition to the Q&A linked above, see [*Lesson: Classes and Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/), especially "Using the `this` Keyword."